# Grails GIS Application

Tags: grails, gis

I'm working on an internal IT application monitoring outages for a network with a national footprint in the US. I'm considering overlaying outages by region on a map. Showing outage areas in red for example. The user clicks on the outage area displaying drill down information. The technology stack includes Grails/JBoss/Linux. Are there frameworks that provide the mapping/GIS layer of the display on which I could overlay my domain specific information? I've looked into the Google Map API, but am unable to leverage it as this operates behind a firewall. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapGuide open source with Openlayers as a UI front end would make a good combination for this. From there the issue would be finding a basemap that fits the needs of the app - data.gov is a good spot to look for US information.